# Do we need to check whether parameter is missing in Rails get request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-get, restful-url, url-parameters

I'm working on a Rails + React web app. And there's one GET request which needs a parameter `trainee_id`.

My question is:

Do I need to add `params.require(:trainee_id)` and relative exception handler to verify the existence of the parameter?

**Route:**
**GET /results/trainees/:trainee_id/published**

```
def get_trainee_published_result
 result = Result.find_by(user_id: params[:trainee_id])
 ...
 do stuff
 ...
end
```

I feel uncomfortable to use this parameter without checking. However, it seems that if the parameter is missing, the route would be invalid and this `get_trainee_published_result` action wouldn't even be triggered.

There would also be some problems with Rspec testing if I include `params.require(:trainee_id)` in my code. I could not test the case when parameter is missing (let(:params) { { trainee_id: nil } } ) because no route would match this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, if a single defined route is the only way your controller action gets called, then the `trainee_id` param will always be present. If you want to be validate this, you could write a [routing spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs) that verifies `GET /results/trainees/:trainee_id/published` calls your action with the given params:

```rb
expect(get: '/results/trainees/123/published')
  .to route_to(controller: 'trainees', action: 'published', trainee_id: '123')
```

As for your action itself, I'd consider representing that you expect `trainee_id` to always be present by accessing it via [`params.fetch(:trainee_id)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-fetch). If for any reason, `trainee_id` isn't available in `params`, that will throw a `ActionController::ParameterMissing` error and the rest of your action won't complete.

If you wanted, you could check for this in a controller spec:

```rb
it 'throws an error when :trainee_id is missing' do
  expect { get :published, params: { }) }.to raise_error(ActionController::ParameterMissing)
end
```